# Program to create a virtual operating system

Tags: virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What virtualization software to use?](https://superuser.com/questions/12626/what-virtualization-software-to-use)

I am looking for a program so I can install Windows 7 Pro on my machine, but in a virtual environment. What program should I download? I don't really want to spend any money on this though. I am currently on Windows XP SP3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) gets my vote. Other alternatives include Microsoft's [VirtualPC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/) and [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/).

Comment: Thanks Virtual Box seems like a really good bit of software